# Is it possible to reference a dataframe in a SQL join?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering about ways to exploit in-memory processing with spark SQL. What are the currently supported approaches for running spark SQL with in-memory objects if any?

- is it possible to have the target of a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement be a table in memory?
- is it possible to reference an in-memory object such as a dataframe in a `FROM` clause?

My current understanding of spark is limited, so please pardon my question if it seems too simple. I would appreciate any advise or guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataFrame's are SQL wrapper around Spark RDDs.
RDDs are immutable(you cannot change them) but can transform or create new RDD from it.

You can register the dataframe as a temporary table
// Register the DataFrames as a table.

`peopleDataFrame.registerTempTable("people")`

Then run select SQLs to get the results.

// SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.

`val results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people")`

So running mostly any select query should not be a problem as long as dataframe supports it.

But because of immutability, i doubt if CREATE TABLE AS will work and would not make sense as we can only doing READ-ONLY operations.

I hope it helps.

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks.